# Find a point within a polygon

Tags: polygon, point, concave

Is there a way to find a point in a polygon? I don't want to find whether a point is in a polygon but want to find the inside point itself. I tried to use the average of x co-ordinates and the average of y co-ordinates to obtain the centroid of a polygon, but this does not apply in the case of certain polygons, such as the following, where the centroid is outside.

[image]

Comment: There are many potential points inside your polygon - which point are you looking for? If you can't clearly define it, then you can't write an algorithm to find it. You may be thinking the point mid-way between those two closest-together vertices in your diagram, but that's very specific to this polygon. Imagine a ring-shaped polygon (like a washer) - where is its centre? Or maybe you don't care, you just want any old point somewhere inside the polygon? If this is the case it's actually quite easy, but you need to define what point you want.

Comment: What matters is that the point is in the polygon. It can be any point.

Answer (score 1):

There may be more efficient ways. But one method to solve the problem is to decompose it into to parts:

1. Triangulate the polygon into a set of triangles. This is always possible. See for example de Burg's "Computational Geometry" book (2nd ed. ch 3).

In your example, the polygon can be obviously decomposed into two triangles.

2. Pick the [incenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incenter) of any of the component triangles. The incenter of a triangle is inside the triangle itself, and is therefore inside the original polygon.

[image: incenter]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a polygon with n Vertices where `V_n = (x_n,y_n)`, you could do this:

1. Compute points `A = (max(x_n),max(y_n))` and `B = (min(x_n),min(y_n))`. Check if both points are actually vertices, if not proceed to the next step, but if **both** points are vertices, take the points `C = (max(x_n),min(y_n))` and `D = (min(x_n),max(y_n))` instead.
2. Intersect the line `AB` (or `CD`) with the polygon (i.e. intersect it with every edge and test every vertex wether it lies on that line).
3. For all points you got in the previous step, compute their distance to `A` (or `C` respectively), order them by increasing distance to `A`.
4. Starting with the point closest to A (which is A itself if A is a vertex), pick a point between that point and the next closest. Test if that point is inside the polygon. If it is you're done, if it is not, repeat this step with the next point (which is the second point of your last iteration).

### Explanation

The rectangle `ACBD` is the axis aligned bounding box of your polygon, so every point that's inside the polygon will also be inside that rectangle. `AB` and `CD` are the diagonals of that rectangle.

In step 1 we check if both points `A` and `B` are vertices, this is important. If one of them is not, we can be sure that at least one vertex of the polygon is "above" the diagonal and at least one vertex is "below", so the diagonal will intersect the polygon.

If both points are vertices, we could be dealing with a triangle where the diagonal is actually an edge or a concave polygon that is completely on one side of the diagonal, therefore we just switch the diagonal and are guaranteed that the other diagonal will intersect the polygon.

Since we know that our diagonal intersects the polygon, we can just iterate through all line-segments and pick a point from each to see if it is inside, one of them has to be. Usually it will be the first line segment that you test, but there are special cases that may cause this segment to be outside of the polygon (again: concave polygon and your first intersection is a vertex rather than an edge), but at least one segment has to be inside.

I assume this could be done more efficiently, but if n is small enough and you don't need to do that for a large number of polygons, there should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

To find any non-specific point that is inside the polygon is quite easy. You need to know the winding order of the polygon (clockwise or anti-clockwise) - this determines which is the inside and which is the outside of the polygon. Here's how:

1. Use the [ear-clipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation) method to find a single triangle ("ear").
2. Find the mid-point of that triangle.

I could reproduce exactly how that works here, but it's well documented already, just use the Wikipedia link and search for further info on ear clipping for polygon triangulation.

Comment: Assuming you have the points in order or each vertex knows its neighbors (which is a resonable assumption) **and** this is a simple polygon, this is probably the best approach. However, you don't need to compute the midpoint: For every triangle `ABC` the point `P = x*A + y*B + z*C` with `0<x,y,z<1` and `x+y+z = 1` is inside the triangle, so you can just take three numbers with these properties and compute a point inside the triangle.

Comment: To elaborate, `x,y,z` are the barycentric coordinates of a point inside a triangle and you are guaranteed that any triangle is convex (which means that the point lies in the convex hull of the triangle).

Comment: Absolutely. Any point in the triangle is valid, just that the mid-point is the most obvious one to calculate (v1+v2+v3) / 3 - which is equivalent to what @mmgross said where x = y = z = 1/3rd

Answer (score 0):

Short of a full blown algorithm you can do the following:

Say I have a polygon which I have added to the points in clockwise order:

```
    p.addPoint(100, 200);
    p.addPoint(200, 100);
    p.addPoint(160, 200);
    p.addPoint(200, 300);
    for(i=0; i<p.npoints; i++) {
      int[] p0={p.xpoints[i], h-1-p.ypoints[i]}, p1={p.xpoints[(i+1)%p.npoints], h-1-p.ypoints[(i+1)%p.npoints]}, p2={p.xpoints[(i+2)%p.npoints], h-1-p.ypoints[(i+2)%p.npoints]};
      System.out.println(" angle "+angle(p0, p1, p2));
    }
```

That is take three consequtive points and determine the angle p0, p1, p2 (in this order p1 is the corner of the angle) as the side p2-p1 turns around to meet side p0-p2 in clockwise order): if it is less than 180 degrees its a convex angle and you can get some point inside it (e.g. take the middle points of the two sides and find the middle point of their connecting line etc.)

If it is more than 180 continue.

angle() is a method to find the angle.

h-1-p[] is needed if you want to convert coordinates to the usual geometrical system (h is the height of the window); otherwise dont use it.

In sum: find a convex corner, whether with the angle approach or some other approach.

Answer (score 0):

Arriving at this question quite late but there is an approach documented [here](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=1256)

> 1. Identify a convex vertex v; let its adjacent vertices be a and b.
> 2. For each other vertex q do:
>      2a. If q is inside avb, compute distance to v (orthogonal to ab).
>      2b. Save point q if distance is a new min.
> 3. If no point is inside, return midpoint of ab, or centroid of avb.
> 4. Else if some point inside, qv is internal: return its midpoint.

I have coded up a [javascript version here](https://github.com/rowanwins/generate-point-in-polygon)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be done using only elementary geometry (no triangulation, ear-clipping, etc.) and in $O(n)$ time, at least when the polygon is simple.

Pick any three consecutive vertices $A$, $B$, $C$ of your polygon, and look at the corner at $B$. This corner (assuming $B$ is a simple vertex) delimitates the inside from the outside of the polygon, and if you know the orientation of the polygon (if you don't, it is quite easy to compute) you know which side is which.

The bisector of this angle is supported by a vector perpendicular to $(C-A)$; if your polygon is counter-clockwise, then the vector $i(C-A)$ points inside the polygon, otherwise $-i(C-A)$ points inside (using complex numbers here for simplicity). This means that, for any ε small enough, $P = B+ε i(C-A)$ lies inside the polygon.

Here, “small enough” just means that the segment $BP$ does not cross any other side of the polygon, so just choose ε smaller than the smallest distance between $B$ and any other side of the polygon (that is, other than $AB$ and $BC$), divided by the norm of $AC$. (This is the $O(n)$ part of the algorithm).